# maxEdits and minPrefix parameters in IndexBasedSpellChecker are not causing any effect on spell check term suggestion

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I have implemented IndexBasedSpellChecker in Solr with following configuration.
But the parameters maxEdits and minPrefix are not causing any effect on spell checked terms suggested by solr

```
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">spell</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
  <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
  <str name="accuracy">0.5</str>
  <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
  <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
  <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
  <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
  <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
  <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
  <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
  <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
  <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
  <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents -->
  <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
 
</lst>

<!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->

<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
  <str name="field">name</str>
  <str name="combineWords">true</str>
  <str name="breakWords">true</str>
  <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
</lst>
```

For miss spelled query **Clathing** the suggestions are:

```
"spellcheck":{
"suggestions":[
  "clathing",{
    "numFound":10,
    "startOffset":0,
    "endOffset":8,
    "origFreq":0,
    "suggestion":[{
        "word":"clothing",
        "freq":77},
      {
        "word":"catching",
        "freq":9},
      {
        "word":"clapping",
        "freq":1},
      {
        "word":"flashing",
        "freq":1},
      {
        "word":"playthings",
        "freq":4},
      {
        "word":"matching",
        "freq":39},
      {
        "word":"anything",
        "freq":18},
      {
        "word":"nothing",
        "freq":12},
      {
        "word":"teaching",
        "freq":8},
      {
        "word":"aching",
        "freq":2}]}],
```

as we can see, it is suggesting **flashing**, **matching** etc... , which doesn't have minimum matching prefix of 1 character with query term **Clathing**

But for same configuration in **DirectSolrSpellChecker** I got suggested terms which have minimum common prefix of 1 character as shown below

```
  "suggestions":[
  "clathing",{
    "numFound":4,
    "startOffset":0,
    "endOffset":8,
    "origFreq":0,
    "suggestion":[{
        "word":"clothing",
        "freq":77},
      {
        "word":"catching",
        "freq":9},
      {
        "word":"clapping",
        "freq":1},
      {
        "word":"coating",
        "freq":5}]}],
```

So why in IndexBasedSpellChecker minPrefix and maxEdits and not working?

Comment: The parameters [you are using are specific to the `DirectSolrSpellChecker` module](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/spell-checking.html#directsolrspellchecker). They're not general parameters usable for any of the spell checkers.

Comment: Then if I want to add maxEdits and minPrefix functionalities in IndexBasedSpellChecker how can I do that, is there any way?